# Relaying dissalowed Spring boot with Zoho

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail, zoho

I am using Spring Boot and I have configured Zoho mail as smtp server. Following are my application properties pertaining to mail

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.zoho.com
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.username= emialid
spring.mail.password = password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed to close server connection after message failures; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as <"Faran Anjum"@DESKTOP-3PBLRKB>
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as <"Faran Anjum"@DESKTOP-3PBLRKB>

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2267)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:2045)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:448)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at com.palmgrid.preparify.module.emailService.GmailSender.sendEmailThroughTemplate(GmailSender.java:46)
    at com.palmgrid.preparify.module.emailService.GmailSender$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1c05267.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(grails) com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as zoho mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501424/grails-com-sun-mail-smtp-smtpsendfailedexception-553-relaying-disallowed-as-z)

Comment: Yes. the answer that is marked correct didn't solved the problem. The second one by "imbond" did resolved the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention setFrom() with an email address that you use as the username for auth.
Make sure that the username and the from address are same.